# How to get last visible row, if rows are hidden or not hidden by filter in Google Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, row, selection

Only lastRow1 shows me the wrong value, if rows are hidden. How to ignore hidden rows?

```
function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow1 = s.getLastRow();
  var lastRow2 = s.getActiveRange().getLastRow();
  Browser.msgBox(lastRow1);
  Browser.msgBox(lastRow2);
  if (lastRow1 == lastRow2) {
    // Do something.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When the following sample situation, you want to retrieve `5` as `lastRow`.

  [image]
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification point:

- In this case, `lastRow` is retrieved with `isRowHiddenByUser`.

#### Modified script:

```
function x() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = 0;
  for (var i = s.getLastRow(); i > 0; i--) {
    if (!s.isRowHiddenByUser(i)) {
      lastRow = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  console.log(lastRow); // or Browser.msgBox(lastRow);
}
```

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve `lastRow` from the sheet with the hidden rows by the basic filter, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
    if (!s.isRowHiddenByUser(i)) {
    ```
  - To

    ```
    if (!s.isRowHiddenByFilter(i)) {
    ```

#### References:

- [isRowHiddenByUser(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyuserrowposition)
- [isRowHiddenByFilter(rowPosition)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#isrowhiddenbyfilterrowposition)