# Download images only from Filtered Cells

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

In my sheet I have more then 1000 image URL's. This code download all the images in there respective cells which is fine but It's too much data.

```
function getImages() {
  const sheetName = "Daily Data"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const cellA1Notation = "I2:I"; // Please set the cell range as a1Notation.
  const imageWidth = 200; // Please set the width you want.
  const imageHeight = 150; // Please set the height you want.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange(cellA1Notation + sheet.getLastRow());
  const urls = dataRange.getValues().flat();
  
  urls.forEach(function(url, i) {
    if (url) {
      const image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url).build();
      const cell = sheet.getRange(i + 2, 9);
      cell.setValue(image);
      sheet.setRowHeight(cell.getRow(), imageHeight).setColumnWidth(cell.getColumn(), imageWidth);
    }
  });
}
```

So I apply the filter function in my sheet. The Problem is above code download all the images and I want to download images only from filtered cells. I tried this code but it's giving me error.

TypeError: filter.match is not a function

```
function getFilteredRange() {
  const sheetName = "Daily Data"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const cellA1Notation = "I2:I"; // Please set the cell range as a1Notation.
  const imageWidth = 200; // Please set the width you want.
  const imageHeight = 150; // Please set the height you want.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange(cellA1Notation + sheet.getLastRow());
  const filter = sheet.getFilter();
  const filteredRows = filter ? filter.getRange().getValues()
                                .map((row, index) => filter.match(index + 1) ? index : -1)
                                .filter(index => index >= 0) : [];
  const urls = filteredRows.map(index => dataRange.getCell(index + 1, 1).getValue());

  urls.forEach(function(url, i) {
    const image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url).build();
    const cell = sheet.getRange(filteredRows[i] + 2, 9);
    cell.setValue(image);
    sheet.setRowHeight(cell.getRow(), imageHeight).setColumnWidth(cell.getColumn(), imageWidth);
  });
}
```

Is there is any solution for it. Either it download all the images in filtered area or any way I delete all the data outside filtered area except header then I Use my old code to download the images.

Comment: Hi and welcome. "So I apply the filter function in my sheet." Riiiight. that would be `const filter = sheet.getFilter();` [Doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getfilter) says "Returns the filter in this sheet, or null if there is no filter." Just to be clear; this calls an **existing** filter; just as `filter.getRange()` refers to an **existing** filter. Would you please provide a definition of your filter OR the filter that you are trying to create/reference.

Comment: _can you please fix the code because..._ At the risk of repeating myself, would you please describe (exactly) the filter that you are trying to use/create.

Answer (score 0):

This is Google Apps, right?  Are you looking for the getRange() method?  As the error message says there is no filter.match() method. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#getRange()

Comment: can you please fix the code because I gather it from different sources and I don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 0):

The script is an adaptation of the StackOverFlow answer to [How to get last visible row, if rows are hidden or not hidden by filter in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61851714/1330560) by @Tanaike. But it should be noted that this is a very common topic and there are many more precedents and solutions available on this subject.

The features of this answer are:

- allows the user to manually apply a filter (or not) to the data column.
- uses `isRowHiddenByUser` and `isRowHiddenByFilter` to creates an array of urls displayed by the filter.
- uses `indexOf` to loop through ALL the urls but process only those that are in the array of filtered urls.

---

```
function hiddenAndFilteredRows2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName)
  var cellA1Notation = "I2:I"; // Please set the cell range as a1Notation.
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(cellA1Notation + sheet.getLastRow());
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: data range = "+dataRange.getA1Notation())
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  // Logger.log(data) // DEBUG
  var unhiddenArray = []
  
  // note data starts at row 2, so test i+2
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(i+2)) {
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", row#"+(i+2)+", url:"+data[i][0]+" :hidden by user")
      continue
    }
    if(sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i+2)) {
       // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", row#"+(i+2)+", url:"+data[i][0]+" :hidden by filter")
      continue
    }
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", row#"+(i+2)+", url:"+data[i][0]+" :not hidden")
    unhiddenArray.push(data[i][0])
  }
  // Logger.log(unhiddenArray) // DEBUG

  // apply code from "getImages"
  var imageWidth = 200; // Please set the width you want.
  var imageHeight = 150; // Please set the height you want.
  var urls = data.flat()
  // Logger.log(urls) // DEBUG
  
  // loop through ALL the urls 
  // but only process those that are in the unhiddenArray
  for (i=0;i<urls.length;i++){
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: i:"+i+", row:"+(i+2)+", url:"+urls[i])
    if (unhiddenArray.indexOf(urls[i]) !=-1){
      var image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(urls[i]).build();
      var cell = sheet.getRange(i + 2, 9);
      cell.setValue(image);
      sheet.setRowHeight(cell.getRow(), imageHeight).setColumnWidth(cell.getColumn(), imageWidth);
    }
  }
}
```

---

**RAW DATA**

[image: raw data]

---

**FILTERED DATA** (text contains "400px")

[image: filtered data]

---

**unhiddenArray**

[image: filtered urls]

---

**Processed data**

[image: processed data]